# Passing variables to another variable in an include possible?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm working on creating a new site for myself and was curious if it's possible to pass a variable to another variable inside an include. What I have is an include that houses an excerpt conditional. If there is no excerpt then it'll grab the_content and strip out any URLs. I'm just trying to pass a word count. Here's what I have.

As you can see, I'm attempting to pass `$wordcount`

Main template:

```
<?php 
  $wordcount = '10';
  include(locate_template('loop-templates/content-excerpt.php'));
?>
```

The include:

```
<?php
  if ( ! has_excerpt() ) {
    $content = wp_trim_words(wp_strip_all_tags( get_the_content(), $wordcount )) ;
    $regex = "@(https?://([-\w\.]+[-\w])+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.#-]*(\?\S+)?[^\.\s])?)?)@";
    echo preg_replace($regex, ' ', $content);
  }else {
    the_excerpt();
  }
?>
```

Any help would be great!!

Comment: What leads you to believe it is not working? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Variable scoping in PHP is global, so $wordcount is available already in your include

Comment: @dave I've set the $wordcount as '10', but it is completely ignored. No errors either.

Comment: Maybe you should change string to number like; $wordcount = 10; (ignore the quotes)

Answer (score 1):

put this in function.php

```
function print_copntent($wordcount){
if ( ! has_excerpt() ) {
    $content = wp_trim_words(wp_strip_all_tags( get_the_content(), $wordcount )) ;
    $regex = "@(https?://([-\w\.]+[-\w])+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.#-]*(\?\S+)?[^\.\s])?)?)@";
    echo preg_replace($regex, ' ', $content);
  }else {
    the_excerpt();
  }
}
```

in template file call the function;

```
<?php print_content(10); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot. My dyslectic code read

```php
wp_trim_words(wp_strip_all_tags( get_the_content(), $wordcount ))
```

when it should have been

```php
wp_strip_all_tags(wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), $wordcount ))
```